# Angular Firestore Issue

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore in my Angular components and I insert these imports to do it:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

Then I do `db = firebase.firestore()` and I can do Firestore operations normally. But with one component I have I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)

I'm initializing Firebase by importing it in app.module.ts using AngularFireModule.initializeApp() with the Firebase configuration values. I also import AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFirestoreModule, and AngularFireStorageModule in app.module.ts.

I've tried deleting and remaking the component. I can also run other components' Firestore code, then go to the component and it still gives that error, so it isn't running before Firebase initializes.

Comment: Would you like to edit the question to share with us exactly how you are initializing Firebase, since that's what the error message is about?  We should be able to duplicate the behavior using the code you provide.  You might want to also do a web search for that error message since it's very common.

Comment: Done. I've tried googling the error code but the issues and solutions that come up seem different to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use initializeApp before @NgModule in AppModule

```
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
```